# message-box new line and customize

Tags: elisp

`(message "abc\ndef")` displays a two line message, while
`(message-box "%s" "abc\ndef")` does not.  Can the controlled two line
display be replicated in message-box?

Also, `M-x customize` didn't seem to have a section for customizing 
the message-box appearance (e.g. different background colors for the OK vs
the message).  Can message-box's appearance be customized?

Can either of these issues be remedied by going to a pop-up 
(of some sort, e.g. x-popup-dialog), or some other emacs package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, `message-box` does not allow that. It simply removes the newline char.
2. No, there is no customization for `message-box`.
3. `x-pop-dialog` won't help either. It too removes newline chars.
4. And neither will `display-message-or-buffer`.

Your best bet is probably to display a buffer that shows whatever complex text you like, and then read user input - either a character or a string.  You can use `read-char` and the like to read a char, and you can use `read-from-minibuffer`, `read-string`, `completing-read` and the like to read a string.

See also variable (option) `use-dialog-box`.

Comment: I'd be happy to.  How?  Where on the page is the hot spot for accepting the answer?